# How many ways are there to distribute 8 teachers to 4 schools where each school must get at least 1 teacher?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Additional details: the teachers are considered distinct from one another.

So here is what I thought:

1) Choose four teachers to go to each one of the schools: $\binom{8}{4}\cdot4!$

2) For each of those situations, distribute the other 4 teachers to the 4 schools: $4^4$

So total: $\binom{8}{4}\cdot4!\cdot4^4$

However, I am almost 100% sure that I am over-counting but can't quite put my finger on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For any actual way, the choice of which four teachers are assigned in step (1)  is not uniquely determined, so your method counts each single way multiple times.

Comment: The answer that was posted by the OP is indeed correct.

Comment: Looking in another way: We have 8 teachers, out of which we first pick a group of 4 people which can be done in $8C_4$ ways. We ask them each to choose 1 school and that can be done in $4!$ ways. Now the remaining 4 teachers are free to choose whichever school that they want and that is $4^4$ ways. Hence the total is $8C_4\times 4! \times 4^4$

Comment: But which four form the first group and which four form the second group? For example, take the one way: ABCDE to school 1, F to 2, G to 3 and H to 4. You are counting that one way 5 different times by various choices {x,F,G,H | x = A,B,C,D,E} for the "first picked group of 4."

Comment: @Ned I'm so crossed with myself that I overlook this. But I'm wondering what's the reduction that will be required to avoid these duplicates or is it a bad approach for this problem.

Comment: It's not a practical approach, because the reduction factor (e.g. the "5" in the example I used) is not uniform for different types of assignments, so it just won't work to first assign one teacher to each school, assign the others arbitrarily, and then fix it up at the end. Rather, you want to treat all eight teachers alike from the beginning, and using inclusion-exclusion as Andre did is what you would find in most or all combinatorics texts that covered this sort of problem. I don't know of any good way to do it using only permutations, combinations, and the multiplication principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use Inclusion/Exclusion. There are $4^8$ ways to assign the $8$ teachers, with no restrictions.

We need to remove the **bad** assignments, where some school(s) get no teacher.

Let the schools be A, B, C, D. There are $3^8$ ways to assign the teachers, avoiding school $A$. There are also $3^8$ ways to avoid schools B, C, D, for a total of $\binom{4}{1}3^8$.

However, this overcounts the bad assignments. For example, $\binom{4}{1}3^8$ counts twice the assignments that avoid schools A and B. The same is true for all the $\binom{4}{2}$ pairs of schools. So to count the bad assignments, we must subtract $\binom{4}{2}2^8$.

But we have subtracted too much, for we have subtracted one too many times the assignments that avoid all schools but A, also the ones that avoid all schoola but B, or all but C, or all but D. So we must add back $\binom{4}{3}1^8$.

The total number of good assignments is therefore 
$$4^8-\binom{4}{1}3^8+\binom{4}{2}2^8-\binom{4}{3}1^8.$$

**Remark:** The counting is presumably not being done by a School Board, since a Board is likely to consider teachers indistinguishable.

Comment: Sir, will you just let me know why $4^8$ and not $8^4$? Actually I get confused in such problems.

Comment: We line up the teachers, by age, or beauty, whatever we wish. Now start assigning schools. The first teacher in the list can be assigined in $4$ ways. or each such assignment, the second teacher in the list can be assigned in $4$ ways. And so on (remember we are at this stage not considering the restriction each school must get at least one teacher).

Comment: Many thanks! Your answers are always informative and complete.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Minor note: $\binom{4}{2}3^8$ in the 3rd paragraph should be $\binom{4}{1}3^8$? (lol @ ending remark)

Comment: @dlaser: Thanks for spotting the wrong binomial coefficient. Perhaps incorporating laser in my user name would help in typo-spotting.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Haha if so, perhaps incorporating Andre into my user name will help me ace my exam tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using exponential generating functions.

The EGF of this problem is:

$\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+
\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}\right)^4$

to solve the problem we can use

$(e^x-1)^4$

for that expression. This expands out to

$ 1-4 e^x+6 e^{2 x}-4 e^{3 x}+e^{4 x}$

this can expanded by hand or taken over to Wolfram Alpha. We get:

$x^4+2 x^5+\frac{13 x^6}{6}+\frac{5 x^7}{3}+
\frac{81 x^8}{80}+...+$

The coefficient of x^8 is the one we want and we multiply that by 8!

$\dfrac{81}{80}\cdot 8! = 40824$

That is the number of ways.